# Return iterator vs Return whole list in Python?

Tags: python, performance, time-complexity, space-complexity

I tested some code for knowing which one is effective, returning iterator and returning whole list.

The program is about reading all lines of `.txt` file (really big size) and create word counting dictionary (Python3.4).

1.Returning iterator

```
from collections import defaultdict
import time

def create_word_cnt_dict(line_iter):
    doc_vector = defaultdict(int)
    for line in line_iter:
        for word in line.split():
            doc_vector[word] += 1
    return dict(doc_vector)

def read_doc(doc_file):
    with open(doc_file) as f :
        while True:
            line = f.readline()
            if not line:
                break
            yield line

t0 = time.time()
line_iter = read_doc("./doc1.txt")
doc_vector = create_word_cnt_dict(line_iter)
t1 = time.time()
print(t1-t0)
```

It takes, `3.765739917755127`

2.Returning whole list

```
from collections import defaultdict
import time

def create_word_cnt_dict(line_list):
    doc_vector = defaultdict(int)
    for line in line_list:
        for word in line.split():
            doc_vector[word] += 1
    return dict(doc_vector)

def read_doc1(doc_file):
    with open(doc_file) as f :
        lines = f.readlines()
        return lines

t0 = time.time()
lines = read_doc1("./doc1.txt")
doc_vector = create_word_cnt_dict(lines)
t1 = time.time()
print(t1-t0)
```

It takes, `3.6890149116516113`

As you can see, returning whole list is much faster.

But in respect of memory usage, Returning iterator is much more effective than returing whole list.

In book `Effective Python`, it recommends returning iterator for efficient memory usage. But I think that time complexity is more important than space complexity these days because todays computer has enough memory.

Please, give me some advices.

Comment: Depends on how much ram you have really. If you are using lists/files w/ 1M plus lines, iterator is the way to go. For normal at home coding, I usually just suck in a whole file.

Comment: Keep in mind that for this bit of code it might make more sense to use the [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects) object.

Comment: There is no specific question here, just a request for discussion.

Comment: @Kupiakos Thanks for your advice : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, I think your interpretation of "much faster" is different than mine. . . The timing differences are on the order of a few percent which isn't very much (likely not user noticeable unless your program runs for *hours* and then the difference is insignificant.)

Couple that with the fact that iterators give you more flexibility.  What if you want to stop reading lines when you process a certain one?  In that case, the iterator could be factors of 2 or more faster because you've gained the ability to "short circuit".

For the short circuiting reason and memory, I'd prefer the generator function here.

<sup>Also note that your timings might be biased by the fact that you're reading a file.  `readlines` is probably going to be more efficient because python can read the file in even larger chunks than it normally would which means fewer calls to the OS.  Many other applications won't have this sublety...</sup>

Comment: Thanks, but in case of readlines, how can I convert every line into lowercase? Do I have look all over each line again for it?

Answer (score 1):

Depends.

If we are talking about a relatively small amount of data then time-complexity won't differ either.

Think about huge amount of data and I am not talking about `Gbs` or `TBs`, much larger data set that huge companies like Google and Facebook need to handle every day, do you think that `space complexity` doesn't count as `time complexity` does?

Space we are not talking about storage memory obviously but for `RAM`.

So your question is quite broad and it depends on the application, the amount of data that you are going to use and your requirements. For relatively small dataset I don't think that time complexity will be a huge deal neither space complexity.

Answer (score 0):

The performance difference is actually very slight.

In light of that, a good programmer would choose the generator version because it is robust.

If you slurp the whole file you are setting a trap. At some point in the future someone (maybe you) will try to pass in 1GB or 10GB, and they will get screwed over, and run around cursing "WHY??????"